# GWT celltable load list<string> into table

Tags: java, string, list, gwt, gwt-celltable

I read the example of a celltable [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html), it use for load data this structure:

```
 private static final List<Contact> CONTACTS = Arrays.asList(
  new Contact("John", new Date(80, 4, 12), "123 Fourth Avenue"),
  new Contact("Joe", new Date(85, 2, 22), "22 Lance Ln"),
  new Contact("George", new Date(46, 6, 6), "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue"));
```

if I have a simple list of string how can put my List into this type of structure?

Comment: Do you want to use `String` instead of `Contact` type? And what's your problem? But are you sure that you need **CellTable** in this case? Table implies displaying of information distributed by columns. If you have simple list in single column, output it as simple list. Don't complicate.

Comment: my external aplication send 3 information as array of string how can capture this 3 info and add to this structure?

Comment: Is your array only 3 equivalent strings or info objects with 3 different field as string in each of them? Show code you have please.

Comment: i have private static final List<Contact> CONTACTS; and a list with many string i need to load this string into the celltable

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of Strings then you would be displaying them in a [ListBox](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwListBox). If you still intend to use it in a CellTable then wrap the String in a Model/POJO/Bean object.

```
Example - String "name" is wrapped in "ContactInfo" Bean.
```

You can then use ContactInfo with CellTable. Cell Widgets all work with MVP design Model -> View -> Presenter

```
ContactInfo -> Model
CellTable -> View
ListDataProvider -> Presenter
```